# accessing Desktop from Root directory

Tags: 15.04, gnome-terminal, root

I was using aircrack-ng package in my ubuntu 15.04. This package works only under root privileges. Now I want to save **.cap file** on my desktop using airodump-ng package but everytime I do, it throws an error

> -bash: cd: Desktop/: No such file or directory

Please let me know how can I access Desktop from my root directory. I am using **"sudo -i"** to become the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is a shortcut to your home directory. So you'd type `cd ~` to get to your home directory, or `cd ~/Desktop` to get to your desktop.

However, if you've used `sudo su` to become root, this won't work - it'll take you to root's home directory.

`cd /home/<your username>/Desktop` will always take you to your desktop folder if you have access permissions. I'm not sure if there's a faster way while logged in as root.

Comment: I am using "sudo -i" to become the root and still not working.

Comment: `sudo -i` still sets you as root, and your home directory is still `/root`.

Comment: but I am unable to write data on my Desktop from root directory.

Comment: @dexter, what error do you get? Or where does it write to, if it succeeds?

Comment: My error is same as the mentioned in the question and I intend to write on the Desktop which is the normal Desktop of our computer.

Comment: @dexter then you still aren't using the correct command. Use the command at the start of the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

**sudo su**

**cd //**

**cd /home/YoUrUSErNaMe/Desktop**

*Remember that any file now you copy on the desktop **only the root user** can access it.